# How to add background image using css without having images being duplicated

Tags: css, image, background

I want to make login form using hmtl , css and one function with javascript, but when i add image url to my body class in css i get displayed few images instead of one that fits the whole screen size.
Any solution?

[enter image description here][1]

Comment: https://prnt.sc/SYXIniInPryS

Answer (score 0):

how are you adding the image, with `background-image`?
You could try to add also `background-size: cover`, which will scale the image (while preserving its ratio) to the smallest possible size to fill the whole container.

example

```css
body {
    background-image: ...
    background-size: cover;
}
```

You can read more about it [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size)